# How to get a MAX and a COUNT from a three table join?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, join

I got an interview question where there's a Car sale modeled in a DB. Each `Car` represents a physical car in a Car sale which refers to a `Make` and a `Model` table. A `Sale` table keeps track of each `Car` that is sold. A `Sale` only consists of one `Car`, so there's a record in `Sale` per every unique `Car` that had been sold.

The question was to find-out the name of the most sold `Model` in the car sale. I answered with a 3-level nested query. The interviewer specifically asked for a solution using joins where I only succeeded in just joining the tables without the aggregates.

How would you join 3 tables as below (Car, Make, Sale) while using two other aggregates?

Here's a rough sketch of the schema. The most sold `Model` here should return 'Corolla'

```
Car

| carid|  modid | etc...
_________________
|  1   |    1   |
|  2   |    1   |
|  3   |    1   |
|  4   |    2   |
|  5   |    2   |

Make

| mkid |  name  |
_________________
|  1   | Toyota |
|  2   | Nissan |
|  3   |  Chevy |
|  4   |  Merc  |
|  5   |  Ford  |

Model

| modid|  name   | mkid |
________________________
|  1   |  Corolla|  1
|  2   |  Sunny  |  2
|  3   |  Carina |  1
|  4   |  Skyline|  2
|  5   |  Focus  |  5

Sale

|  sid |  carid | etc...
_________________
|  1   |    1   |
|  2   |    2   |
|  3   |    3   |
|  4   |    4   |
|  5   |    5   |
```

Edit:

Using MS SQL Server 2008

Output needed:

```
Model Name |  Count
_____________________
Corolla    |    3
```

i.e. The model of the `Car` that has been sold the most.
Notice only 3 Corollas and 2 Sunnys are in the `Car` table while `Sale` table corresponds to each of those with other sales detail. The 5 `Sale` records are actually Corolla, Corolla, Corolla, Sunnnu and Sunny.

Comment: What result set are you looking for? Can you edit your question to show the expected result set in tabular form?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `SQL Server 2008`, make use of `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function`.

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  c.name, COUNT(*) [Count],
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM    Sale a
            INNER JOIN Car b
                ON a.carid = b.carID
            INNER JOIN Model c
                ON b.modID = c.modID
    GROUP   BY c.Name
)
SELECT name, [Count]
FROM recordList
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6158/2)

Answer (score 2):

When interviewers ask for this they usually want you to say that you'd use windowed functions. You could give each sale a unique ascending number partitioned by model and the highest sale number you'd get would be the max count.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on your newly added SQL Server 2008 tag.  If you are using a different RDBMS you'll probably need to use `limit` instead of `top` and place it at the end of the `top_sold_car` subquery.

```
select Make.name as Make, Model.name as Model
from (
    select top 1 count(*) as num_sold
    from Car
    group by modid
    order by num_sold desc) as top_sold_car
join Model
    on (top_sold_car.modid = Model.modid)
join Make
    on (Model.mkid = Make.mkid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following query works on oracle 11g . here's [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a519f/27/1)

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT model.name AS name FROM car  , sale , model
    WHERE car.carid=sale.carid
      AND car.modid=model.modid 
    GROUP BY model.name
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Or

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT model.name AS name FROM car  natural join sale natural join model    
    GROUP BY model.name
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|    NAME |
-----------
| Corolla |
```